# MLP with backpropagation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to build a MLP network with a hidden layer which has 7 neurons. I tried to use newff() and train() in Matlab, but I got this error:
"Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'network'."

here is my code:

```
mytrain = mytrain';
train_class = train_class';
net = newff(minmax(mytrain),[7 1],{'logsig' 'logsig'}, 'traingd');
net.trainParam.epochs = 100;
net = train(net,mytrain,train_class); % the error comes from here
A = sim(net,mytrain);
```

Any idea would be helpful. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seems all problem came from:

```
mytrain = mytrain';
train_class = train_class';
```

I removed these two, and write the code like this:

```
net = newff(minmax(mytrain),[7 1],{'logsig' 'logsig'}, 'traingd');
net.trainParam.epochs = 100;
net = train(net,mytrain',train_class'); % I put the transpose command here
```

and it worked !!!